# How to keep ObservedObject SKScene up to date with SpriteKit's presented Scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swiftui, skscene

Right now I am setting up SwiftUI to use as my UI in SpriteKit game. I have it set up so my game launches and works fine. My UI view is set up like this

```
struct GameView: View{
    @ObservedObject var scene: GameScene
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            //UI
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(scene.name!)").foregroundColor(.red)
                    Button(action: {
                        scene.goBack()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Return")
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        scene.tryEnter()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Enter")
                    })
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.trailing)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so I can go back with goBack()? Problem is, that my ObservedObject scene is still set to my OriginScene and returns View as NIL, because it is not presented atm.

```
func goBack(){
    guard map.originScene != nil else { return }
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: map.originScene!.name!) {
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
        view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```